# How can I safely insert mongo documents from json posts on my flask API?

Tags: mongodb, authentication, flask, pymongo

I have an android game that pushes usage data to a flask service in json format. When the request comes in, I'm just inserting the json straight into the mongo collection where I'm keeping statistics.

Is this unsafe? How can I, in Flask, ensure that the post requests are coming from my game before I insert them into the mongo collection?

Comment: Trusting client data is generally unsafe. I'd recommend the data is validated before saving to your database.

Answer (score 1):

I'm doing the same thing as you describe in my project(we don't do any validation, btw). If you users don't have to login into game, you don't have much options. You can use [CSRF tokens](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery), but this option is not safe enough. Other option is to generate this "requests" from application server, instead of client. This will ensure, that data is not compromised.